# UFT Application area - how to associate web add in to application area

Tags: testing, qtp

I have created a new business component in UFT and linked the correct application area to it. I cant add anything to the object repository as the web add in is not associated to it
I am trying to associate the web add-in to an application area and cant seem to do so.
I have checked out the application area. The properties pane is blank and settings is greyed out. I cant seem to find any method off associating the application area to the web add in.
The web add in is loaded on UFT start up

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the application area in the solution explorer, then you should be able to associate Web in the properties pane.

[image: Screenshot of UFT]